# MSBuild Conditional based on Constants

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono

So I'm trying to build a C# project in Mono.  I want to include a reference to `System.Deployment` conditional on the presence or absence of the `__MonoCS__` constant that the Mono Compiler defines.  I'm not sure if those constants are even defined yet when MSBuild gets a hold of my .csproj though.

I think I might have to Add a Mono configuration which would define a MONO constant and then i can remove the reference to `System.Deployment` and conditionally compile the lines i need with an `#if MONO` command...but it would be so much easier if I could simply add `Condition="Defined(__MonoCS__)"` to the line in question and call it good...

Comment: Even for adding a "Defined(__MonoCS__)", you would need to tell xbuild that __MonoCS__ is actually defined, probably through DefineConstants property. But you would be defining that only for a mono configuration, then might as well add that mono configuration and conditionally reference System.Deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are unfortunately getting things backwards. The compiler constants are never passed back to MSBuild, the chain of invocation is MSBuild -> Compiler -> Preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was wondering...So the typical way of doing this is to create a Mono build configuration and to remove the references for that config?

Comment: Yes that would be the most common way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Mono has [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3010) in xbuild (MSBuild equivalent) which makes it very hard to define conditions like this.

Want to try to fix the bug? Should be easy, but I actually didn't have time yet to try.